# Cycles material for road- asphalt

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials

I know there is another post on this but I didn't get that very well. Can someone post a cycles material for asphalt with the displacement? 
Also, if you can do so, can you draw on that with Texture Paint with the paint being a part of the bump as well? Like drawing the lines on the road.

Comment: Here are some free road textures published for Blender a short while ago. https://www.blendernation.com/2018/11/29/49-pbr-road-textures-for-free-cc0/ . As for Texture painting, yes you can just create a new texture do your painting then use the the Cycles Nodes to mix it in. Have ago and if you get stuck come back with your screen shots and .blend file. https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'll check it out. So good to see free PBR textures!